# TheCatApi discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

So today I was trying to add a command to my discord bot that would allow it to connect to [TheCatApi](https://thecatapi.com), and I was unable to do it due to multiple errors. Here's my code below:

```py
import nextcord
import os
from nextcord import Interaction, SlashOption
from nextcord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import catapi

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

api = catapi.CatApi(api_key=os.environ['CAT_API_KEY'])

def run_coro(coroutine):
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)


class Fun(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  testServerID = 827933970742116442

  @nextcord.slash_command(name = "cat", description = "Sends a random cat photo uwu", guild_ids=[testServerID])
  async def cat(self, interaction: Interaction):
    
    results = run_coro(api.search_images(limit=1))
    print(results[0].url)
    await interaction.response.send_message("heer")





print("Loaded cog: Fun.py")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Fun(client))
```

And the monumental error below:

```
Ignoring exception in on_interaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/client.py", line 415, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/client.py", line 1741, in on_interaction
    await self.process_application_commands(interaction)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/client.py", line 1757, in process_application_commands
    await app_cmd.call_from_interaction(interaction)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/application_command.py", line 1182, in call_from_interaction
    await self.call(self._state, interaction, interaction.data.get("options", {}))
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/application_command.py", line 1186, in call
    await super().call(state, interaction, option_data)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/app
Loaded cog: Extras.py
Loaded cog: Time.py
Loaded cog: MathShit.py
Loaded cog: Admin.py
Loaded cog: Fun.py
The bot is running sir! Logged in as Meowsicle bot#4403
-------------------------------------------------------
Ignoring exception in on_interaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/client.py", line 415, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/client.py", line 1741, in on_interaction
    await self.process_application_commands(interaction)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/client.py", line 1757, in process_application_commands
    await app_cmd.call_from_interaction(interaction)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/application_command.py", line 1182, in call_from_interaction
    await self.call(self._state, interaction, interaction.data.get("options", {}))
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/application_command.py", line 1186, in call
    await super().call(state, interaction, option_data)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/application_command.py", line 663, in call
    await self.call_invoke_slash(state, interaction, option_data)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/application_command.py", line 704, in call_invoke_slash
    await self.invoke_slash(interaction, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/application_command.py", line 719, in invoke_slash
    await self.callback(self._self_argument, interaction, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/cogs/Fun.py", line 27, in cat
    results = run_coro(api.search_images(limit=1))
  File "/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/cogs/Fun.py", line 14, in run_coro
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 592, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 554, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
/home/runner/Meowsicle-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/client.py:422: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'CatApi.search_images' was never awaited
  pass
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I have tried putting different parts of code in and out of the class, reformatting the code, even deleting the entire thing and rewriting it and I achieved nothing. I'm using [this](https://github.com/ephreal/catapi.py) async wrapper for the API connection. That's all of the detail I can give you but stackoverflow is asking for more.... Anyways, thanks in advance to anyone who can help! Thanks again, and good luck to anyone who decides to try and help!

Comment: Sorry for kinda weird spelling and stuff at the end but I needed "more explanation"

Comment: `asyncio.new_event_loop()`, probably not needed -- if this is a fork of D.PY, there's already an event loop created internally. Also, why are you using `runcoro` inside of an asynchronous function? You can simply use `await`, can't you?

Comment: I honestly have no idea about this, I'm kinda new to programming and especially using apis, and I'm doing what the github repository I linked shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i have something that might help you

Heres the code i wrote:

```
import requests
import nextcord 
from nextcord import Interaction
from nextcord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    guild_id = 'your_id'

    @nextcord.slash_command(name="cat", guild_ids=[guild_id])
    async def cat(self, interaction: Interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        data = requests.get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search")
        data = data.json()
        get = data[0]
        result = get["url"]
        embed = nextcord.Embed(
            title="A Cat",
            color=nextcord.Color.random()
        )
        embed.set_image(url=result)
        await interaction.edit_original_message(embed=embed)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Test(client))
```

Comment: [Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71648275/edit) your answer to contain explanations of the code and why/how it works will add much more value to an answer than just a block of code. Remember, you're not _just_ trying to answer the OP; you're also helping developers in the future with this same problem. See [answer] for more information on writing good answers.